# Why is it not possible to create an instance of type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, creating an instance of `type` parameter is illegal, so the following code won't work:

```
class Gen<T> {
    T ob;
    Gen() {
        ob = new T(); // Illegal!!!
    }
}
```

The reason behind this is:

> T does not exist at runtime, then how would the compiler know what
>   type of object to create.

But what I fail to understand is, using `erasure` the following code will translate to:

```
class Gen {
    Object ob;
    Gen() {
        ob = new Object(); // Perfectly Fine!!!
    }
}
```

Because:

> When your Java code is compiled, all generic type information is
>   removed (erased). This means replacing type parameters with their
>   bound type, which is `Object` if no explicit bound is specified.

So why instantiating a `type` parameter is illegal?

Comment: Wht if `T` is an Interface or an abstract class?

Comment: @Jens Won't it basically work the same way? As the `return-type` and `parameters` will be **erased** in this case.

Comment: You can not instanciate an Interface nor an Abstract class

Comment: @GhostCat I would have accepted it as soon as I understood your answer, was bounded by waiting time of SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple: because that `T` could be anything.

Assume you have a `Gen<Integer>`. Surprise: Integer does **not** have a default constructor. So how do you intend to do `new Integer()` then?

The compiler can't **know** whether there is a default constructor for the thing that comes in as `T`.

`java.lang.Object` obviously has such a constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I get the point now. Every `Java class` won't have a default constructor defined for them. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It's more than just there is no default constructor in general: it's that the constructor to be invoked is chosen at compile time, and that requires you to know which class it will be invoked on at compile time.

Comment: @AndyTurner And the generics don't know that till run-time, that makes sense.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri no: owing to type erasure, the type is *never* known at this point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal when the type is unknown during runtime. This is due to type erasure.

Yet if you give your method or constructor the information about the type by passing the class of the type, then you can instantiate an object of that type using reflection - as long as there is a suitable constructor.

For example this is possible:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gen<T> {

    T ob;
    Gen(Class<T> tClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        ob = tClass.newInstance(); // legal if class has default constructor!!!
    }

    public T getOb() {
        return ob;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Gen<JFrame> genFrame = new Gen<>(JFrame.class);
        if((genFrame.getOb() == null)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        Gen<JPanel> genPanel = new Gen<>(JPanel.class);
        if(genPanel.getOb() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```